# Jenkins maven release credentials

Tags: maven, jenkins, cloudbees, maven-release-plugin

I'm currently using cloudbees with bitbucket.

I've been trying to configure the release of the maven projects. To perform the release I'm using the `Maven Release Plug-in Plug-in`.

The test project that I'm trying to release is able to update from the mercurial repository, change and tag the versions and it tries to upload the released artifact to the private cloudbees release repository.
The problem I'm facing is that it is not able to authenticate against this repository. From what I understand, I have to add to the settings.xml the credentials for the repository. And this rises some doubts:

- Why I can upload from the job the resulting artifact using a post build action but it needs to authenticate when using the release plugin?
- Isn't there some better way to authenticate against the repository than trough username and password? ssh for example.

Answer (score 1):

Which repo are you talking about? The Maven one where you push the artifact or the BitBucket one where you push a new tag and update the version number of the current branch? You will need both.

Adding the Cloudbees credentials in the settings.xml in your *private* folder is fine. This is the same you are setting in your local Maven repo (`~/.m2/settings.xml`) to fetch from Cloudbee's Maven repo.

Comment: I'm talking about the Maven artifacts repository. What do you mean by private folder?

Comment: you have 4 cloudbees repositories: snapshot, release, backup and private. copy your settings.xml to private, so jenkins can access your snapshot and release repositories